# How to get OR product of all values of a column of group

Tags: sql, postgresql, bitwise-operators

Consider below data

```
 user_id | group_id
---------------------------
   1     |   1
   1     |   2
   1     |   4
   2     |   1
   2     |   8
```

let's say the table name is `user_group`. I want following output

```
 user_id  |  groups // binary or operation on all values of a user
--------------------
 1        |  7      // i.e.  1 | 2 | 4 = 7
 2        |  9      // i.e.  1 | 8 = 9
```

So far I can get array of all group_id's. But there is no way to get **or** product of all values in that array.

```
user_id   |  groups
--------------------   
  1       |  {1, 2, 4}
  2       |  {1, 8}
```

query: `select user_id, array_agg(group_id) from user_group group by user_id`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do

```
select user_id, bit_or(group_id) from user_group group by user_id;
```

There doesn't seem to be any reason to use an array aggregation here.